# How do I set up a custom navbar and a custom collapse? The right does not line up in mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**bootply (http://bootply.com/99184)**

in mobile view, collapsed search button(right-side) is lower than text(left-side)

I want text and collapsed search button in the same line (look-style)

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I put the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Demo: http://jsbin.com/ojUbevul/1/edit?html,css,output

## http://jsbin.com/ojUbevul/2

This is from looking at examples and reading the docs. I was hoping someone else familiar with BS3 would answer this. You actually don't need to do any of the previous answers if you structure your html the correct way via the docs and examples on GetBootstrap.com.

```
<div class="navbar">
 <!-- if it has no bg color-->
 <form class="form-inline">
  <!--form wraps entire bar-->
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">     <span class="sr-only">Toggle Search    </span> Search Icon     </button>

    <!--/custom text here- -->
    <div class="navbar-custom-left">
     <strong> <a href="?kind=recv">Received </a>
    
 ( <a title="안읽은쪽지" href="?kind=recv&amp;unread=only"> <span class="red">197 </span> </a> / <a href="?kind=$kind">507</a> / 
 <a href="?kind=recv&amp;sfl=me_file&amp;stx=me_file">??
 </a>)
 </strong>
    </div>
    <!--end custom text-->

   </div>
   <!--/.navbar-header- -->

   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <div class="navbar-right navbar-form">
     <div class="form-group" role="search">
      <select name="sfl" class="form-control" id="sfl">
       <option value="me_subject_memo">제목+내용    </option>
       <option value="me_subject">제목    </option>
       <option value="me_memo">내용    </option>
       <option value="me_send_mb_nick">보낸(별명)    </option>
       <option value="me_send_mb_id">보낸(아이디)    </option>
      </select>
     </div>
     <!--/.form-group -->
 
     <div class="form-group">
      <input name="stx" class="form-control" required maxlength="15" value="" itemname="검색어" type="text">
     </div>
     <!--/.form-group -->
 
     <button class="btn btn-primary">검색    </button>
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-right navbar-form-->

   </div>
   <!--/.nav-collapse -->

  </div>
  <!--/.container -->

 </form>
 <!--/.form-inline navbar-form navbar-right -->

</div>
<!--/.navbar navbar-default -->



/* --------- CSS ---------- */
.navbar-custom-left {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.red {color:red}
```

Comment: thanks. I got answer from bootply.com's source code. and found that text height and button height is different. I read and view getbootstrap.com's docs but needs more examples.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem is the padding and margin-top on the search element. To fix it, try removing these lines

```
padding: 9px 10px;
margin-top: 8px;
```

from the following CSS:

```
.navbar-toggle {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `line-height` as the height of your elements. add a class to your container and style set `line-height`:

[**DEMO**](http://bootply.com/99191)

HTML

```
<div class="container lineheight34">  <!-- lineheight34 is an example -->
...
</div>
```

CSS

```
.lineheight34{
    line-height:34px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed "button" to "a".

from

```
<button class="navbar-toggle"
```

to

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar"
```

bootply (http://bootply.com/99206)